# Submit without submit button

Tags: javascript

I have created dropdown menu "Users", whith 2 options to select

```
<select name="Users">
        <option>User1</option>
        <option>User2</option>
</select>
```

I'm stuck with next thing i want to do, which is:
-if user1 is selected, another dropdown menu is generated
-if user2 is selected, input windows is generated

I would like changes to be made without submit button. Changes should be made with selection on "users" dropdown menu.

Any tips or solution will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I shouldn't suggest you this but here's something what you need http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: but don't use mysql_ extension like in example from w3schools (its outdated!)

Comment: Use JS  <option onclick="doSomething(this);">A</option> and AJAX :)

Answer (score 2):

You need Javascript http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

PHP is server side language and it generates code only while user is loading the page not after its already loaded. 
If you want users to get code inside their browser, after some their action you need User side language as Javascript.

It will be easier for you if you use some Javascript library as jQuery http://www.jquery.com .

Comment: I have absolutely no experience in java programming. Could you be more specific on how to write such a script

Comment: Its not Java its Javascript :)
Check those 2 links which I gave you. There are examples

Comment: I check link but i can't figure it out. Would you mind to post the simple code for my problem. I pretty much don't know what to do. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery events and use change event of select box to show and hide any html elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Users" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option>User1</option>
        <option>User2</option>
</select>
```